How to Combine Responses from Two APIs into a Single Payload in Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)?
I am working with Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) and have encountered a challenge. I need to combine the responses from two different APIs into a single payload.
Here are the sample responses from the two APIs:
API 1 Response (Customers):
json

{ "Customers": [ { "CustomerID": "c8239", "CustomerName": "Robert", "CustomerEmail": "robert@gmail.com" }, { "CustomerID": "c3242", "CustomerName": "John", "CustomerEmail": "john@gmail.com" }, { "CustomerID": "c4544", "CustomerName": "David", "CustomerEmail": "david@gmail.com" } ] }
API 2 Response (Orders):
json

{ "Order": [ { "OrderID": "o232", "OrderAmount": "15000" }, { "OrderID": "o231", "OrderAmount": "18000" }, { "OrderID": "0233", "OrderAmount": "17000" } ] }
I need to combine these responses into a single payload where each customer is paired with an order, as follows:
Combined Response:
json

{ "Combine": [ { "Customer": [ { "CustomerID": "c8239", "CustomerName": "Robert", "CustomerEmail": "robert@gmail.com" } ], "Order": [ { "OrderID": "o232", "OrderAmount": "15000" } ] }, { "Customer": [ { "CustomerID": "c3242", "CustomerName": "John", "CustomerEmail": "john@gmail.com" } ], "Order": [ { "OrderID": "o231", "OrderAmount": "18000" } ] }, { "Customer": [ { "CustomerID": "c4544", "CustomerName": "David", "CustomerEmail": "david@gmail.com" } ], "Order": [ { "OrderID": "0233", "OrderAmount": "17000" } ] } ] }
Additional Details:

Objective: I want to merge the customer data from the first API with the order data from the second API into a single, combined payload.

Tools: I am using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) and exploring the use of Data Stitch and other OIC features to achieve this.

Constraints: The number of customers and orders may vary, and they may not always have a one-to-one correspondence.



How would you know which order belongs to a specific customer if there is no 1 to 1 relation between them? If you have 3 customers and 5 orders - what would be your combined response?

No need  to bother about this constraint.if we have exact corresponding order for each  customer, how can we achieve this...?

If there is no link between customers and orders I assume that it is irrelevant which order belongs to which customer:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  api_data ( id, customers, orders ) AS
    ( Select 1 as id, 
             JSON_SERIALIZE( '{ "Customers": [ { "CustomerID": "c8239", "CustomerName": "Robert", "CustomerEmail": "robert@gmail.com" }, { "CustomerID": "c3242", "CustomerName": "John", "CustomerEmail": "john@gmail.com" }, { "CustomerID": "c4544", "CustomerName": "David", "CustomerEmail": "david@gmail.com" } ] }' PRETTY ) as customers,
             JSON_SERIALIZE( '{ "Order": [ { "OrderID": "o232", "OrderAmount": "15000" }, { "OrderID": "o231", "OrderAmount": "18000" }, { "OrderID": "0233", "OrderAmount": "17000" } ] }' PRETTY ) as orders
      From Dual
    ),

Use JSON_TABLE to extract columns from your api data and join them to get all the data from both sources in rows
  grid AS 
    ( Select  cst.rn, cst.customer_id, cst.customer_name, cst.customer_mail, 
              ord.order_id, ord.order_amount
      From ( Select ROWNUM as rn, c.*
             From   api_data a,
                    JSON_TABLE ( a.customers, '$.Customers[*]'
                                 Columns ( customer_id   Varchar2(12)    PATH '$[0].CustomerID',
                                           customer_name Varchar2(24)    PATH '$[0].CustomerName', 
                                           customer_mail Varchar2(24)    PATH '$[0].CustomerEmail'
                                         )
                               ) c
           ) cst
    Inner Join ( Select ROWNUM as rn, o.*
                From   api_data a,
                       JSON_TABLE ( a.orders, '$.Order[*]'
                                    Columns ( order_id     Varchar2(12)     PATH '$[0].OrderID',
                                              order_amount Number(14, 2)    PATH '$[0].OrderAmount'
                                             )
                                  ) o
           ) ord ON( ord.rn = cst.rn )
    )

Generate your combined json data using json functions:
SELECT   json_object( 'Combine' 
                       VALUE  json_arrayagg( json_object('Customer' VALUE customers, 
                                                         'Order'    VALUE orders )
                                           )
         )as cust_ord
FROM  ( Select    rn,
                  json_array( json_object('CustomerID'     VALUE customer_id,
                                          'CustomerName'   VALUE customer_name,
                                          'CustomerEmail'  VALUE customer_mail )
                           ) as customers, 
                  json_array( json_object('OrderID'       VALUE order_id,
                                          'OrderAmount'   VALUE To_Char(order_amount) )
                            ) as orders
       From   grid
      )

R e s u l t :
{ "Combine":[ 
                {
                    "Customer": [   {"CustomerID":"c8239","CustomerName":"Robert","CustomerEmail":robert@gmail.com}
                                ],
                    "Order":    [   {"OrderID":"o232","OrderAmount":15000}
                                ]
                },
                {   "Customer": [   {"CustomerID":"c3242","CustomerName":"John","CustomerEmail":john@gmail.com}
                                ],
                    "Order":    [   {"OrderID":"o231","OrderAmount":18000}
                                ]
                },
                {   "Customer": [   {"CustomerID":"c4544","CustomerName":"David","CustomerEmail":david@gmail.com}
                                ],
                    "Order":    [   {"OrderID":"0233","OrderAmount":17000}
                                ]
                }
                
            ]
}


If we assume your assumptions about the fact that ORDERS are in the same order as CUSTOMERS and thus also there is only 1 ORDER per customer, are correct, then you can join 2 JSON_TABLE with a "FOR ORDINALITY" column in each and do the JOIN condition on it:
with customers(js) as (
    select q'~{ "Customers": [ { "CustomerID": "c8239", "CustomerName": "Robert", "CustomerEmail": "robert@gmail.com" }, { "CustomerID": "c3242", "CustomerName": "John", "CustomerEmail": "john@gmail.com" }, { "CustomerID": "c4544", "CustomerName": "David", "CustomerEmail": "david@gmail.com" } ] }~'
),
orders (js) as (
    select q'~{ "Order": [ { "OrderID": "o232", "OrderAmount": "15000" }, { "OrderID": "o231", "OrderAmount": "18000" }, { "OrderID": "0233", "OrderAmount": "17000" } ] }~' 
),
customers_js (idx, js) as (
    select idx, custjs from customers c,
    json_table(
        c.js,
        '$.Customers[*]'
        columns (
            idx for ordinality,
            custjs format json path '$'  
        )
    )
),
orders_js(idx,js) as (
    select idx, orderjs from orders o,
    json_table(
        o.js,
        '$.Order[*]'
        columns (
            idx for ordinality,
            orderjs format json path '$'  
        )
    )
)
select 
    json_object(
        'Combine' is 
        json_arrayagg(
            json_object('Customer' value json_array(c.js), 'Order' is json_array(o.js)) 
        )
    )
from customers_js c
join orders_js o using(idx)
;


{"Combine":[{"Customer":[{"CustomerID":"c8239","CustomerName":"Robert","CustomerEmail":"robert@gmail.com"}],"Order":[{"OrderID":"o232","OrderAmount":"15000"}]},{"Customer":[{"CustomerID":"c3242","CustomerName":"John","CustomerEmail":"john@gmail.com"}],"Order":[{"OrderID":"o231","OrderAmount":"18000"}]},{"Customer":[{"CustomerID":"c4544","CustomerName":"David","CustomerEmail":"david@gmail.com"}],"Order":[{"OrderID":"0233","OrderAmount":"17000"}]}]}

